# File not found from resources folder

Tags: java

I have a file in my src/main/resources folder, the location of which i am passing in library function, but the file is not being read.

here is how the folder structure looks on decompiling the war 
.

I have a file in my src/main/resources folder(Intuit.cto.gateway.aws.preprod.jks), the location of which i am passing in library function, but the file is not being read.

here is how the folder structure looks on decompiling the war.
[image]

when i create a simple maven project and try to do the same, i am able to access the file from src/main/resources
when i decompile my sample project it looks like this
[image: here i am able to access this file]

To access the file, i am using this code :

```
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{    
          FileReader fr=new FileReader("src/main/resources/filename");    
          int i;    
          while((i=fr.read())!=-1)    
          System.out.print((char)i);    
          fr.close();    
    }
```

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Use Classloader and getResourceAsStream, `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename")`

Comment: i cant chhange teh way how to read the file, i am using a 3rd pary library to which i'm passing the file location. The library is reading the file using FileInputStream

Comment: But *you* locate the file. Do it with `ClassLoader` and pass it to your library.

Comment: i need to pass a string

Comment: Could you post the code you are actually using then? Maybe you can't have the file in the resources folder but rather in the file system.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it the way you want to.

Your path is most likely incorrect. Unzip your `*.war` file and see that `src/main` is no more.

If the war file is not exploded, you can't access its content by using simply path passed to a `File*` class, because your file is packaged as in zipped into standard location in a ZIP file with file extension WAR.

If your destination requires `File` or path which is passed to `FileReader` you have to read this file out of WAR file (using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`) and copying it out to a temporary location like `File.createTempFile()` or `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`.

Answer (score 1):

A resource (on the class path) is not necessarily a file system file. If the usage cannot deal with just an InputStream, one needs to create a temp file.

```
Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("phoneid-", ".jks");
InputStream res = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Intuit/gateway/preProd.jks");
// Case-sensitive, absolute path on the class path.
Files.copy(res, tempFile);
// Maybe:
//tempFile.toFile().deleteOnExit();

String param = tempFile.toString();
```

(A result `null` for getResource/getResourceAsStream indicates a wrong path.)

A partial solution would also be to check the URL of the resource, whether has the "file:" protocol, and not "jar:file:" (packed in a zip format, like jar, ear or war).

```
URL url getClass().getResource("/Intuit/gateway/preProd.jks");
```

With a class, the path can either be relative to the class package directory, or absolute ("/..."). If using the ClassLoader instead the path is always absolute, and should be written without `/` in front.